# Add "Checked" to radio button, either from cookie, or based on assigned class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm including some accessibility tools to a project I'm working on.
I have very little jQuery experience. So far I've followed an excellent guide by James Hibbard, which has brought me quite far. I'm able to change font, size and contrast via radio buttons, and save it to a cookie so the selected choices are remembered.

I'm stuck at getting the radio buttons to show "checked" for the right choice.

Ideally I would load from the cookie, and add "checked" to the appropriate radio button. But alternatively, I could read the class applied to , and use that to determine the checked box.

The script is more or less 1:1 ripped from the guide I followed.

Following the guide, each value is separated by a hyphen ("-"), starting with what it changes plus the actual value, as an example, value="text-sans" for the regular Sans Serif font, and value="text-dyslexic" for the speciality font.

Font selection works wonderfully.

Currently I have no ID for each radio button, I tried to add an ID, and add checked="checked" via jQuery, but I am nowhere near experienced enough to write that from scratch, as evidenced by the past few hour of failing to do so.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function changeStyles(optValue){
      var property = optValue.split("-")[0];
      removeOldClass(property);
      $("body").addClass(optValue);
      $.cookie('bodyClassList', $("body").attr('class'));
    }

    function removeOldClass(property){
      var classList = $("body").attr('class').split(/\s+/);
      $.each(classList, function(index, item){
        if (item.match(property)){
          $("body").removeClass(item);
        }
      });
    }

    $(".selector").change(function(){
      changeStyles(this.value);
    });

    $(".selector > option").each(function() {
      if(
          $.cookie('bodyClassList') != null &&
          $.cookie('bodyClassList')
           .match($(this).val())
        ){
        $(this).attr("selected","selected");
      }
    });

    $("#reset").click(function(){
      $("body").removeClass();
      $(".selector").each(function(){
        $(this[0]).attr('selected', true);
      })
      $.cookie('bodyClassList', null);
    });

    if($.cookie('bodyClassList') != null) {
      $("body").removeClass();
      $("body").addClass($.cookie('bodyClassList'));
    }
  });
```

No error messages so far, I can echo the contents of the cookie, and seeing as the selection is remembered, I know the cookie bit works, yay!

Any help is most welcome.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you also post the html for the elements you want to set? Your text says you want to check a radio button, but the code for `".selector > option"` and `attr("selected","selected")` implies drop down menu options are being selected. The equivalent for radio buttons would involve `input` and `checked` instead.

Comment: Thanks! I made some changes based on what you wrote, specifically I added a div around my <label><input...> with the class .selector, and changed the bit of code to:

    $(".selector >> input").each(function() {
      if(
          $.cookie('bodyClassList') != null &&
          $.cookie('bodyClassList')
           .match($(this).val())
        ){
        $(this).attr("checked","checked");
      }
    });

Works perfectly, any way I can mark this bit as the answer?

Comment: Glad to help you find a solution. Comments can't be marked as answers, and I can't remember if you can upvote comments at lower rep levels. I see you've posted this idea as an answer. You can mark that as the selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of altering the `selected` attribute, try using `prop` ([reference](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)). Here's a quick demo:

```js
$( document ).ready( function() {
  $( '.checker' ).click( function() {
    $( '#check-me' ).prop( 'checked', true );
  } );

  $( '.unchecker' ).click( function() {
    $( '#check-me' ).prop( 'checked', false );
  } );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="checker">Check this</button>
<button class="unchecker">Uncheck this</button>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-me">
```

Let's say you have a cookie with the information `mode: dyslexic` and want to enable that checkbox on page load. With your pattern of `value="text-dyslexic"`, you could have a function that looks like:

```
function activateMode( mode ) {
  $( '.mode-selector' ).find( `input[value="text-${ mode }"]` ).prop( 'checked', true );
}
```

Where `mode` is one of your options 'dyslexic' or 'sans'. Call the function on page load with the cookie value to activate the element, which could then trigger a `change` event handler to execute the desired effects. The `${}` notation is ES6 string interpolation in case that looks unfamiliar, though this will work without it (just make sure to update the syntax).

Answer (score 0):

OXiGEN had the right idea, changed this bit in code:
Notice the .selector >> input, as we go "two levels" down, because of the  tag.

```
$(".selector >> input").each(function() {
  if(
      $.cookie('bodyClassList') != null &&
      $.cookie('bodyClassList')
       .match($(this).val())
    ){
    $(this).attr("checked","checked");
  }
});
```

The HTML for each radio button group now looks like this:

```
  <div class="selector">
    <label><input type="radio" name="text" class="selector" value="text-sans">Regular</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="text" class="selector" value="text-dyslexic">Dyslexic</label>
  </div>
```

And it works beautifully!

Thanks!

Comment: `label` typically sits next to the form element instead of encapsulating the form element. See [example](https://internetingishard.com/html-and-css/forms/#radio-buttons). `".selector > input"` should work then. Note: Check out the rest of the [site](https://internetingishard.com/) I linked; very useful and meaningful content for all levels of experience.